# Change event not fired after uploading a file into a textarea

Tags: jquery, file, events, input

In a html with jQuery usage I've a textarea and a input (type=file). After uploading a file and inserting the content into the textarea the change event of the textarea is not fired. Why?

```
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:100%" rows=10></textarea><br>
<input type="file" accept=".txt" id="upload"><br>
<div id="text-structure">...</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function document_loaded() {
  $("#upload").change(function() {
    var f = $('#upload')[0].files[0];
    if (!f) return;
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) {
      $('#textarea').val(e.target.result);
    }
    r.readAsText(f);
  });
  $("#textarea").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    const l = $("#textarea").val().length;
    $("#text-structure").html("Text length: " + l);    
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pegast/4ndtcry8/

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you programmatically set the value of your texture using `.val()`, it does not trigger any of the events you have attached to the texture (change/keyup/paste). You will have to manually trigger one of these events to get it to work, e.g.:

```
$('#textarea').val(e.target.result).trigger('change');
```

I would also suggest listening to the `input` event instead of the `change` event, even though this has no bearing on the functionality at all.

See example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function document_loaded() {
  $("#upload").change(function() {
    var f = $('#upload')[0].files[0];
    if (!f) return;
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) {
      $('#textarea').val(e.target.result).trigger('change');
    }
    r.readAsText(f);
  });

  $("#textarea").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    const l = $("#textarea").val().length;
    $("#text-structure").html("Text length: " + l);    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:100%" rows=10></textarea><br>
<input type="file" accept=".txt" id="upload"><br>
<div id="text-structure">...</div>
```

However, I personally feel that it might be better to simply abstract the text length function out, so that you don't need to manually dispatch an event (it feels like a code smell to me), and keep things way simpler and straightforward.

Here is a version that does not even use jQuery and does exactly the same as above:

```js
// NOTE: Generic function that updates the text length
function updateTextLength() {
  const l = $("#textarea").val().length;
  $("#text-structure").html("Text length: " + l);  
}

document.querySelector('#upload').addEventListener('input', () => {
  const f = $('#upload')[0].files[0];
    if (!f) return;
    const r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) {
      $('#textarea').val(e.target.result);
      updateTextLength();
    }
    r.readAsText(f);
});

['input', 'keyup', 'paste'].forEach((eventName) => {
  document.querySelector('#textarea').addEventListener(eventName, updateTextLength);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:100%" rows=10></textarea><br>
<input type="file" accept=".txt" id="upload"><br>
<div id="text-structure">...</div>
```